# In Angular 8 how to apply pipe set as property in TS?

Tags: angular

I would like to set a dynamic formatting of data/array in a mat-table.
One of the features is applying a pipe flexibly via a property.

Please have a look at this: [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ykrghm?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

Now when we look at the script file: table-basic-example.ts, we see:

```
tableDef: Array<any> = [
    {
      key: 'position',
      header: 'Position',
      className: 'something',
                              // I add 2 properties:
                              // -------------------
                              // pipeName - for a name of pipe to apply to a data field value
                              //          - date pipe in this case
                              // pipeParams - parameters for the pipe, in this case: 
                              //              format, timezone, locale (for the date pipe)
                              //              ??? NOT SURE if this format is the best way - ???
      pipeName: 'date',
      pipeParams: "'mediumDate':'+0430':'en-US'",

    }, ...
```

Now we go to the HTML template/view file - table-basic-example.html, where we have this section:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let def of tableDef">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="def.key">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{def.header}} </th>
    <td [ngClass]="def.className" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[def.key]}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

In the line that renders the data field values I want to conditionally apply the pipe set above in: tableDef. I am struggling with the syntax of quotation marks and brackets in this case. Here is a simple attempt that needs your wise correction. Thank you.

```
    <td [ngClass]="def.className" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{ (def.pipeName) ? element[def.key] | def.pipeName:def.pipeParams : element[def.key]   }} 
    </td>
```

So the browser would understand it as:

```
    <td [ngClass]="def.className" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{ (def.pipeName) ? element[def.key] | date:'mediumDate':'+0430':'en-US' : element[def.key]   }} 
    </td>
```

The legend of the attempt is:

- **(def.pipeName)**  *- condition - if the field has property - pipeName*
- **?** *- then*
- **element[def.key]** *- field value piped through*
- **|** *- pipe character -*
- **def.pipeName** *- pipe of this name*
- **:def.pipeParams** *- pipe parameters*
- **:** *- otherwise*
- **element[def.key]** *- field value as is*

**Addition:**

I got it partially resolved for a singe pipe - date - with this interpolation line:

```
{{ (def.pipeName=='date') ? (element[def.key] | date:def.pipeParams) : element[def.key] }}
```

But, it would be nice if we could have also the pipe name referenced dynamically, and instead of:

```
 ...  | date:def.pipeParams
```

we would have something like:

```
 ...  | def.pipeName:def.pipeParams
```

Comment: You'll need a big "switch case" for all possible values. This cannot be done dynamically because it wouldn't work with AoT. You can put that switch case into a new pipe which takes the pipe name and arguments as its arguments and then calls the correct one, though.

Answer (score 1):

well, instead make a big "switchCase" in .html, you can add a property pipe to each data element

```
this.data.forEach(x=>{
   switch (x.pipeName)
   {
      case "date":
         x.pipe=new DatePipe('en-US')
         break;
      case "number":
         x.pipe=new DecimalPipe('en-US')
         break;
   }
})
```

Then you can use

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
  {{item.pipe?item.pipe.transform(item.value,item.params):item.value}}
</div>
```

Another is add a property "formatedData"

```
this.data.forEach(x=>{
   switch (x.pipeName)
   {
      case "date":
         x.formatedData=formatDate(x.value,x.params,'en-US')
         break;
      case "number":
         x.formatedData=formatNumber(x.value,x.params,'en-US')
         break;
      default:
         formatedData=value;
   }
})
```

Comment: Manually creating pipe instances will become a nuisance when the pipes have dependencies, so I'd probably create the switch case pipe and inject the required pipes to let DI handle it.